# SQL Server: How can I create a column with the repeating sequence 1-12?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

Long story short, I would like to create a column that repeats the pattern 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,1,2,3,4,...etc. for (12 * 460343 =) 5524116 rows. Any wisdom on how I could complete this? Thank you!

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve with this? Since you're using a database I take it that you have more information stored in each row than just the number.

Comment: I need to create a month column. After some unpivoting I am left with 3 columns: ID, YEAR, VALUE. Each ID has several years, and within that each year has 12 values for each of the twelve months. Everything is currently in the correct order in terms of months, so I just need to add a column that repeats the pattern of 1-12.

Comment: I think that your approach to relational databases is slightly mistaken: rows in a table have no "default order". If you mean that sorted by the `ID` column the rows are in the correct order, then that's an easy thing to accomplish, but make sure that you know this first.

Comment: The rows were imported from a .csv, which had everything "in order." I ended up solving the problem in Excel and then unpivoted it again in SQL Server. It was a work around, not advisable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Insert say 48 then select into from self several times. You will get there real fast. It is surprisingly faster than one would think.

If you create a table with an int autoinc column then at end:

```
delete from table where id>5524116
```

Edit here you go

```
    create table idFix
    (   id bigint auto_increment primary key,
        num int not null
    )engine=myisam;

    -- prime it    
    insert into idFix(num) values (1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9),(10),(11),(12);

    -- this is pretty fast, don't laugh
    -- run the following line 19 times
    insert into idFix(num) select num from idFix;

    -- you now have 6.2m rows (6,291,456)
    select count(*) from idFix

    delete from idFix where id>5524116;

    select count(*) from idFix;

    select min(num),max(num) from idFix;

Takes 3 minutes max

Use your helper table then for the love of Pete drop it !
```

Comment: Thank you for the response! Could you make this a little clearer for me if possible?

Comment: I am about to post the whole thing

Comment: @SQLPolice  That's a first for me Oracle shadow guy !

Comment: @DrewPierce After conquering the `not in`, you're ready for the next stage!

Comment: Sorry i did it with mysql syntax but i guess you tweaked it

Answer (score 1):

Use a loop and do some mod division with your counter.

```
DECLARE @LoopCounter bigint
SET @LoopCounter = 0

CREATE TABLE #YourValues
(
    YourValue_Key int NOT NULL identity (1,1) PRIMARY KEY, 
    YourValue_OneThrough12Repating int
)

WHILE @LoopCounter < 5524116
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO #YourValues (YourValue_OneThrough12Repating) VALUES ((@LoopCounter % 12) + 1)
        SET @LoopCounter = @LoopCounter + 1
    END

SELECT * FROM #YourValues

DROP TABLE #YourValues
```